# Why is the js callback function giving an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".pStyle").CapFirstWord();
});
function CapFirstWord() {
    $word = $(this);
    var k = $word.length;
    alert(k);
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="pStyle">Of all of these "new" selectors, ::nth-letter is likely the most useful. For instance, Lettering.js wraps letters in for us so that we can select individual letters. This would be entirely unnecessary with ::nth-letter.</p>
```

I am trying to create a callback function which can be called from other pages to display the length of a given class/id.

How can I achieve that.

Comment: Why on earth would a regular function be chainable to a jQuery object ?

Comment: What error do you get? (I can make a pretty good guess, but you should make your question clear).

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).CapFirstWord is not a function`

Comment: What do you mean by length, the number of elements with a certain class, or the number of words in the element. It's not at all clear

Comment: The custom function `CapFirstWord` cannot be chained to  a jQuery object. You can pass the selector to it `CapFirstWord ($('.pStyle'))`

Comment: The `length` is just a test. But it can be anything in the future. `length` is this case is number of words in the `pStyle` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to be able to chain your function after a jQuery selector you can  *extend* the default functionality of jQuery using [its `$.fn.extend()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/):

```
$.fn.extend({
    CapFirstWord: function() {
        $word = $(this);
        var k = $word.length;
        alert(k);
    }
});
```

> The `jQuery.fn.extend()` method extends the jQuery prototype (`$.fn`) object to provide new methods that can be chained to the `jQuery()` function.

Then you can call `$(".pStyle").CapFirstWord();`.

#### Demo

```js
$.fn.extend({
    CapFirstWord: function() {
        $word = $(this);
        var k = $word.length;
        alert(k);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".pStyle").CapFirstWord();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="pStyle">Of all of these "new" selectors, ::nth-letter is likely the most useful. For instance, Lettering.js wraps letters in for us so that we can select individual letters. This would be entirely unnecessary with ::nth-letter.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function wrong. You have attempted to chain a regular function to a jquery object.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    CapFirstWord($(".pStyle"));
});
```

Here I have added a parameter to the function, the element that is being passed by the above script:

```
function CapFirstWord($word) {
```

And finally, to get the length of the string, I am calling `.text()` on the element:

```
    var k = $word.text().length;
```

### Final solution:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    CapFirstWord($(".pStyle"));
});

function CapFirstWord($word) {
    var k = $word.text().length;
    alert(k);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery object doesn't have a function called CapFirstWord, that's why it fails. You should call that function passing the jQuery object as argument. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
       CapFirstWord($(".pStyle"));
});
function CapFirstWord(tag) {
    var k = tag.length;
    alert(k);
}
```